# How can I validate access tokens from different providers in Springboot?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I will try to briefly explain part of my app architecture so you can understand what I'm trying to achieve. I think it's a very common scenario but I can't figure out how to implement it in Springboot.

**What I want**
I want to login from my Angular FE using OAuth2 using different providers. In this case I'm using an authorization server implemented in Springboot (2.1.7.RELEASE) and I'm also authenticating against Google Account. Once I have the access token from one provider, I want to access some resources in the BE, but first, the access token must be validated.

**What I have so far**
In my BE, I have the following `AuthorizationServerConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client_id")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("client_secret"))
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        tokenConverter.setSigningKey("SigningKey_VALUE");

        return tokenConverter;
    }
}
```

Then I also have a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that uses an `userDetailsService` to validate the user and a `UserDetailsService` implementation in order to get the users. I could be wrong about what is the main function of the classes I mentioned earlier, but it's a configuration that it is working when I get an access token and then I validate it when it's send to the BE in Authorization headers of the request.

The validation part of every access token attached to the request comes from this resource server (or I think it comes from this class, correct me if I'm wrong):

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/security/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/usuarios/usuarios/**").hasAuthority("ADMINISTRADOR")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        tokenConverter.setSigningKey("SigningKey_VALUE");

        return tokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    protected UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        config.addAllowedOrigin(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        config.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.stream(HttpMethod.values()).map(HttpMethod::name).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return source;
    }
}
```

In my Angular FE, I was able to login with a Google Account, so I have among other data that come from the Google Response, an Access Token and a Id Token. My question is:

**According to my current implementation, how can I start validating these Access Tokens that are obtained by Google?**

Any help would be appreciated. If someone has the answer of how to do this in Springboot, that would be optimal, but I think I could make it work if someone could at least explain how this problem is solved in other languages.

Thanks!

Comment: in the documentation there is a full example of how to set up authentication with google https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-sample-boot

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndolf, but I think I could manage to perform the Google authentication if it were my only provider, I don't know how to manage to validate tokens from different providers. Also, could it be that the example you shared is about configuring a springboot client that uses login with Google? Because in my case I have an Angular client.

Comment: first of all, its not your angular client that does the authenticaten. Its your backend, angular starts the but its the backend that performs the actual authentication.

Comment: second of all, your explanation is not very detailed or exact. You have one authorization service that does the login and issues tokens. You have not posted your authentication manager, so i have no idea what you are authenticating against atm.

Comment: `I want to login from my Angular FE using OAuth2 using different providers` all at the same time? in parallell? selective provider from the user?

Comment: `and I'm also authenticating against Google Account.` can't see that code, no code is provided.

Comment: `Once I have the access token from one provider` are we authenticating in parallell and at first token, you stop the others? clairify

Comment: `userDetailsService` does no validation, it fetches the user information and returns a UserDetails object (principal)

Comment: `I get an access token and then I validate it when it's send to the BE in Authorization headers of the request` you claim to do validation? where? and why do you ask how to do validation if you are already doing it?

Comment: you should read this and understand this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#technical-overview

Comment: some good links https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=caCJAJC41Rk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWiwpvpCrro https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE

Comment: Thanks again @ThomasAndolf, I appreciate your comments, I will try to explain it better. In my Angular client I added the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login, using that I see a pop-up where I can select a Google account and perform login, after that I end up in my FE with a valid Google account that among other data, it contains an access Token. There's no interaction with my BE at that point. What I need is to validate the AT to authorize requests that come from my Angular client with that AT.

Comment: "Are we authenticating in parallell and at first token, you stop the others? clairify". My problem is that a user can perform login using my authorization service or using Google, in either case I end up with a user in my FE with an AT. When the user request data from the BE, the AT is added to the request, so in the BE I need to validate that AT. In my current implementation, AT provided by my Authorization service are correctly validated, but I don't know what I have to change to validate the AT from Google. If the AT gets validated by at least one provider, then the BE will return the data.

Comment: what you do is that you authenticate against google, but then you should not use the google token. You just verify that the user is who they claim, and then you issue a regular token from your issuer